# "Exception while loading the app" without a stack trace

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish, nullpointerexception, jboss-weld

I'm migrating my app from GlassFish 3.0.1 to GlassFish 3.1.1. Deployment fails, with the following error messages:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while shutting down application container
SEVERE: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException. Please see server.log for more details.
```

There is no stack trace. I turned on the root logging level to FINEST, and the first SEVERE message occurs after a Weld message:

```
//...
FINE: WELD-000105 Enabled interceptor types for Manager
Enabled alternatives: [] []
Registered contexts: [interface javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped, interface javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped, interface javax.inject.Singleton, interface javax.enterprise.context.Dependent, interface javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped, interface javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped]
Registered beans: 0
Specialized beans: 0
: []
```

And before several messages like these (for several different classes):

```
FINE: PWC4451: File cannot be read /opt/sun/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/QmsWeb/WEB-INF/classes/org/jboss/seam/transaction/SeamTransaction.class
FINE: PWC4451: File cannot be read /opt/sun/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/QmsWeb/WEB-INF/classes/org/jboss/seam/transaction/SeamTransaction.class
FINE: PWC4451: File cannot be read /opt/sun/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/QmsWeb/WEB-INF/classes/net/sf/ehcache/config/TerracottaConfiguration$ValueMode.class
//...
```

What could be causing this error? Could these PWC4451 messages be indicating that some libraries aren't being loaded?

Comment: This looks like it's going nowhere. If any development tools programmer sees this, remember: good error messages are a feature!

Comment: This is actually flagged as a Glassfish issue and should be fixed in Glassfish 4.0, accordong to the issue. See http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18599, unfortunately this helps neither you or me now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was due to a @ViewScoped bean that did not implement Serializable. Apparently, an older version of Weld that we were using didn't find it objectionable that a passivating-scoped bean wasn't Serializable, but this one failed silently because of it. Oh well, hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 4):

After three hours of debugging I fixed a problem like this trying to deploy the application in JBoss 6.

It seems like several error messages from Weld don't get logged properly under Glassfish. In my case I annotated an EJB with @Stateless @RequestScoped (that is illegal, must be @Statefull).
With Glassfish I could only see that "error while loading the app", while in JBoss 6 I get the correct error message indicating the offending code.

I suggest that you try deploying on JBoss 6 stripping out all the parts (@Resource with specific JNDI path, for instance) that prevent the Weld deployer to scan the application and validate the CDI stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into running my applications on JBoss. Do you know has this bug been reported to the Seam / GlassFish folks?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that my beans.xml consisted of the empty "beans" element, which used to work but apparently doesn't anymore. It worked when I replaced it with a completely empty, 0-byte beans.xml.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks... would have taken a *long* time before i would tried that :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when adding an interceptor that wasn't serializable in `Glassfish 3.1.2.2`.  Just got a `NullPointerException` without any further explanation.

It works fine when I made the interceptor implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

Reason and solutions I have encountered regarding this problem:
- target not updated (make sure to do a maven clean, target folder might be locked, try to manually remove it and rebuild your ear (had this problem a few times)
- problem with JDBC pools: flush them 
- constructor problem with EJB's (note it's the container who creates your beans): the container needs to be able to initiate them. So a default constructor with no arguments has to be present

if that doesn't work:
team->compare to -> latest working version and consider every EJB bean or DTO for webservices as a possible cause of error. Comment your changes and retry to deploy to locate your problem.

In any way it's a nasty error :( Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case and in the spirit of Interceptors, mine was kind of easy to find because i was playing around there.

I adding the innocent @Interceptor on my interceptor even though i'm using it with annotations.

My version of glassfish is 3.1.2.2.

This page says that it is optional [Inteceptor Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptor.html).