# Updating Richfaces from 4.0.2 to 4.2.2 breaks web app deployment

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

An existing and working Netbeans v7.0 project had it's 4 richfaces jars replaced to a newer version after which the project was cleaned and built successfully, the glassfish server was stopped and the web app was deployed unsuccessfully. Here are the error highlights from what was logged:

The netbean "Glassfish Server 3.1" tab:

```
...
INFO: WELD-000900 ${parsedVersion (osgiVersion})
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while shutting down application container
SEVERE: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The netbean projectname "(run-deploy)" tab:

```
...
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=[path-to-project]/build/web&name=MisThirdPartyUpdate&force=true failed on Glasfish Server 3.1
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException. Please see server.log for more details.
[path-to-project]/nbproject/build-impl.xml:782:
The module has not been deployed.
  at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:187)
  at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execution(Deploy.java:106)
  ...[14 more levels]
BUILD FAILED (total time: 23 seconds)
```

server.log file:

```
...
SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while loading the app[#]
SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admon.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while shutting down application container[#]
SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admon.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException[#]
```

Now here is the strange part, if I replace a certain 1 of the 4 richfaces jar files the project deploys and runs perfectly. That is, I replaced richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final.jar with richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar, i.e. I have 3 jars from 4.2.2 and 1 from 4.0.0. As I said earlier, the project will also deploy and run perfectly if I have all 4 Richfaces 4.0.0 jars in the build path.

Here is the exhaustive ordered list of jars in this projects build path when it can not deploy:

```
tomahawk-1.1.8.jar
annotations-4.2.1.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga.jar
sac-1.3.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
primefaces-3.3.jar
hibernate3.jar
mail.jar
poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar
poi-contrib-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar
iText-5.0.4.jar
resolver.jar
xbean.jar
xbean_xpath.jar
xmlbeans-qname.jar
xmlpublic.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
```

I'm using java version 1.6.0_33.

From a similar bug report, ["Exception while loading the app" without a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195243/exception-while-loading-the-app-without-a-stack-trace), I made sure both beans.xml files were zero length. Also, based on this report as well as http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/jee/53-glassfish-31-exception-while-loading, I made sure all my beans with "@SessionScope" implemented Serializable.

To me, the fact that it will run with an older version of one of the richfaces jars should be a big clue.

Any one have any ideas???

Comment: Can you find any details about the NPE?  It would help to see the full stacktrace.  Maybe you'll have to adjust the glassfish log levels to see it.